# Unable to use GCP Cloud Armor due to insufficient quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use "Cloud Armor".

However when trying to create some config (I believe it was the security police) in the console I get an error of:

> Operation type [insert] failed with message "Quota 'SECURITY_POLICIES'
> exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally."

When I try to increase the quota:

> Based on your service usage history, you are not eligible for quota
> increase at this time. Please make use of the current available quota,
> and if additional resources are needed, please contact our Sales Team
> (https://cloud.google.com/contact/) to discuss further options for
> higher quota eligibility.

Upon doing a request for a quota increase I got an email back stating:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We have reviewed your request for additional quota. Unfortunately we
> cannot grant your request.
>
> While evaluating quota requests, we consider several factors,
> including resources that most legitimate customers use, a customer’s
> previous usage and history with Google Cloud Platform. In addition to
> this, we may deny a request for additional quota when there are
> outstanding issues with a billing account for billing quota or paid
> services related quota requests.

So now what do I do? Any ideas? Why is using this so restrictive while cloudflare is much less trouble to setup...

Answer (score 2):

Asking for a quota increase is asking for a credit line increase. Google has declined your request to use the Cloud Armor resource.

There are several options:

1. Wait until you have some payment history.
2. Prepay your account.
3. Use a different payment instrument that has credit available.
4. Contact Google Cloud sales and establish an account relationship.